# What is the name of these icons on Apple watch complications list & where can I access to them?

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch-complication

I downloaded the apple [famous watch app example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/clockkit/creating_and_updating_complications) (Creating and Updating Complications)

in this project, the complications list has a nice gauge icon like below:

[image] [image]

As far as I know, these should be the placeholder icons but all the icons in placeholder assets are these:

[image]

So where is the source of those gauge icons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [`CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicCircularOpenGaugeSimpleText`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/clockkit/clkcomplicationtemplategraphiccircularopengaugesimpletext). (What a mouthful!) The relevant lines are found in line 256 of ComplicationController.swift in the linked sample code.

```
private func createGraphicCircleTemplate(forDate date: Date) -> CLKComplicationTemplate {
    // Create the data providers.
    let percentage = Float(min(data.mgCaffeine(atDate: date) / 500.0, 1.0))
    let gaugeProvider = CLKSimpleGaugeProvider(style: .fill,
                                               gaugeColors: [.green, .yellow, .red],
                                               gaugeColorLocations: [0.0, 300.0 / 500.0, 450.0 / 500.0] as [NSNumber],
                                               fillFraction: percentage)
    
    let mgCaffeineProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: data.mgCaffeineString(atDate: date))
    let mgUnitProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "mg Caffeine", shortText: "mg")
    mgUnitProvider.tintColor = data.color(forCaffeineDose: data.mgCaffeine(atDate: date))
    
    // Create the template using the providers.
    let template = CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicCircularOpenGaugeSimpleText()
    template.gaugeProvider = gaugeProvider
    template.centerTextProvider = mgCaffeineProvider
    template.bottomTextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "mg")
    return template
}
```

It's not an icon/image, just a kind of `CLKComplicationTemplate`.

Comment: OK thanks, but are those icons on the watch complications list are loading from this function from line 256?  I think that line is responsible for the complication itself. not that icon, are you sure!? because in that function I get data from iPhone & it's not efficient if the complications list get the icon from that function.

Comment: @Ahmadreza Yes, ClockKit calls `getLocalizableSampleTemplate` on line 73 to get a placeholder. And you return a `CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicCircularOpenGaugeSimpleText`. The black box of ClockKit knows how to draw that. I'm not sure if there even _is_ an image file. It most likely is dynamically drawn programmatically. And if you say that's inefficient, well, I'm sure you know how to make it more efficient now! Just return a corresponding template in `getLocalizableSampleTemplate` with sample content, without reading from disk.